# How to use Texmaker Synctex - Jump between source and PDF

Tags: texmaker, forward-inverse-search

How to jump between lines in PDF view and source view,

Comment: ctrl+click on the PDF preview or right click and then "click to jump to the line"

Comment: Thank you so much. How about if I want to check the spelling  in my document, it says can not open the dictionary.Why?

Comment: Go to "Options -> Configure TeXMaker -> Editor" and you'll see a "Spelling dictionary" entry. You should check that it points to the directory where the dictionaries are. If it does not, change it to the appropriate directory.

Comment: @dcmst You can always add that as an answer.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I'm seeing someone is voting to close, so I don't see the point in answering...

Comment: @dcmst Well, I don't see the point of closing it, I don't see how this is off-topic. (Edit: If a clear duplicate exists, fine, I haven't looked, but closing as off-topic is IMO wrong.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I have revoked my close vote -- it was too early, admitted

Comment: Searching for “jump” in the user's manual easily reveals the shortcut: “If you add the `-synctex=1` option to the `pdflatex` command, the built-in pdf viewer will jump directly to the position in the PDF file that corresponds to the current line in the (La)TeX source file.
Reciprocally, with a right-clic on a word in the built-in pdf viewer (context menu), the editor will jump to the corresponding line in the source file.”

Answer (score 12):

To perform an inverse search you can "ctrl+click" on the PDF preview or right click and then clik on "click to jump to the line":

[image]

As @egreg points out, such information are easily found the [user manual](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html):

> If you add the `-synctex=1` option to the `pdflatex` command, the built-in
>   pdf viewer will jump directly to the position in the PDF file that
>   corresponds to the current line in the (La)TeX source file.
>   Reciprocally, with a `right-clic` on a word in the built-in pdf viewer
>   (context menu), the editor will jump to the corresponding line in the
>   source file.
>
> - Remark : if you press the `ctrl+space` key (`ctrl+$` on MacOsX) in the built-in pdf viewer, the focus go to the editor.

Comment: this doesn't work on my texmaker, do you know why?

Comment: @domenico this doesn't work on my texmaker too. Could you please help?
When I R-Click and select "Click to jump .." nothing happen. Also, "Ctrl+Click" is the same, nothing happen.

Comment: @texenthusiast when I apply stype(fancytikzposter) for box or some thing. If I Ctrl+ Click it will jump to the stype source not main source. How to jump to exactly main source.

Comment: It also doesn't work on my texmaker.