# Can I make the preview of texmaker jump to the last page automatically after compiling?

Tags: texmaker, viewers

When I do a preview I want to see immediately what changed in the PDF. Since in my case this is at the end of the document I do not want the behaviour the texmaker shows the first page each time. How can I change this? **cmd + arrow** down unfortunately does not work for scrolling to the end. I noticed that I can click the page numbers. This is already nice.

Comment: Edit: I noticed that I have to press Play again after compiling. When using PDFLaTeX as compiler and PDF Viewer as viewer it ends up in displaying the PDF correctly where I left it. So my new wish is to have it auto-update like in Windows with Sumatra PDF and TeXnicCenter. You see that I am currently evaluating which environment suits me best.

Comment: If I do cmd+click in my code, it jumps to the correct place in my pdf. (TexPad on Mac)

Comment: I do know nothing about `texmaker`, but `texstudio` is very similar and if you enable `synctex` during compilation it will automatically display the part of the document you just edited, so if you work on the last page, it will display the last page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Arne mentioned already, cmd+click (ctrl+click on windows) is one option. Another is via the context menue (right click) jump to pdf.

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202377/how-to-use-texmaker-synctex-jump-between-source-and-pdf) you can find a similar issue.

Regarding your new wish in your comment, I can highly recommend [TeXstudio](http://www.texstudio.org/). I also switched there from Texmaker when I searched for suitable alternatives.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you. This only seems to work for documents without \input. When using input only the way from PDF to code works, not the other way around. The context menu has the same issue. texmaker does not seems to know what linked documents are. I will checkout TeXstudio.

Comment: You're right! I also noticed this and I think this was a reason for me to switch either earlier. I promise you, TeXstudio does. (btw: after including, you can go to the linked file right from your main file by holding ctrl or cmd and clicking on the included link which appears when pressing ctrl or cmd)

Comment: TeXstudio makes a great first impression. Jumping back and forth between code and PDF works here out of the box. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the -synctex=1 option to the pdflatex command. (options -> configure texmaker -> commands)
2. Define a master document from options.

Now the last edited part will be highlighted upon build in texmaker.