# Texmaker: Finding the corresponding code line linked to a section of the PDFLaTeX file

Tags: overleaf, texmaker, sourcecode, shortcut

I've recently started using Texmaker to edit on my LaTeX documents (up to now, I mostly used Overleaf or TeXworks), so I am still new to this program's shortcuts. I have been looking for a shortcut in specific that I can't seem to find, and I would like to know whether this is something this specific LaTeX editor has.

I am working on a lengthy file that has several chapters saved as separate `.tex` documents, which are all called by a single  `main.tex` document. As such, any time I want to edit a specific part of the compiled `.pdf` file, I need to know in which line of which of my subfiles that specific part of the document was encoded - which is always a bit annoying to find.

In Overleaf, this is made simple, since double-clicking on the corresponding line of the .pdf I wanted to edit would link me to the corresponding code line in the document. Does Texmaker also support a similar shortcut? And if so, what is it?

Comment: I don't know texmaker but the system to link the pdf view and the editor is synctex which should give you something to search for

Comment: Thank you for the terminology! It led me directly to what I needed: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202377/how-to-use-texmaker-synctex-jump-between-source-and-pdf